# Почему не обрабатывается исключение?

Tags: python, selenium, обработка-ошибок

Есть функция, которая должна возвращать либо True, либо False если элемент найден или нет

```py
def authCheck(self):
        self.driver.get(self.VK)
        sleep(5)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="index_email"]')
        try:
            print("Вы не авторизированы!")
            return False
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Вы авторизированы!")
            return True
```

Но обрабатывается только в части try, а если авторизация уже произведена, выдает не True а ошибку

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="index_email"]"}       
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но обрабатывается только в части try, а если авторизация уже произведена, выдает не True а ошибку

У вас ошибка возникает в этой строчке: `self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="index_email"]')`, но отлавливаете ошибку здесь:

```
print("Вы не авторизированы!")
return False
```

Вам нужно написать так:

```
try:
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="index_email"]')
    print("Вы не авторизированы!")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Вы авторизированы!")
```

Я бы вам посоветовал получше изучить питон, чтоб в дальнейшем не возникали ошибки и неточности в коде.

Comment: У return False какое назначение?

Comment: @Александр `return False` написал автор вопроса, я же указал на ошибку автора. Если человек умеет писать функции, значит он знает что делает, когда пишет. Если это вы дизлайкнули ответ, то спасибо, что прокомментировали. Хотя не понимаю, зачем дизлайкать сразу, если лучше просто спросить сначала...

Comment: Да это от меня дизлайк.

Comment: Какое True и False если то что должно быть обработано, не помещено в блок.

Comment: @Александр вы пишите:'то что должно быть обработано не помещено в блок' . А что по вашему должно быть помещено в блок? То, что я написал, или что-то другое?

Comment: Просто надо было указать автору вопроса что ему лучше почитать сначала руководство по Python.

Comment: @Александр ну, я решил точно указать на ошибку, что ж за этот порыв помочь сразу дизлайкать? Свой ответ дополню и исправлю.

Comment: Прошу прощения, вчера не важно себя чувствовал.)P.S. лайк вернул.